# VisFileCopy is not working with large files

Tags: large-files, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I'm working in Centura 3.0 team developer and I want to copy large file

`VisFileCopy` is not working with large files.

Unfortunately, I couldn't reach any documentation related to maximum allowable data size or the return errors description.

I do some tests and I've discovered it is working fine with files 5.25 GB and I wanna copy file with 11 GB

```
File Size        State
5.25 GB          Copied
5.62 GB          Not Copied and retrieve Error (-39)
```

Is there an equivalent function of `VisFileCopy` working with large files smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Win32API function SHFileOperation found in SHELL32.DLL.

**Alternatively to the image below, here is an alternate  working version you can download and open into v3.0 .   I've tested it in v6.2 and it works just fine.  If you can't open the download ( because v3 is too old ) , I'll post up an alternate image, which you'll just have to type in from scratch.   But trust me , it does work.**

**Goto:    [SQLWindows Advanced file operations: copy, move, rename and delete](https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/WinApi_Miscellaneous#Advanced_file_operations:_copy.2C_move.2C_rename_and_delete)**

---

**1) Declare SHFileOperation in External functions: ( if not already )**

[image]

**2) Declare some constants used by SHFileOperation:**

[image]

**3) Declare your own wrapper ( to replace VisFileCopy ) as an Internal Function:**

[image]

**4) Call your wrapper function with whatever parameters you want ( e.g. include/ exclude a progress bar )**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you provide your code into text format rather than image?

Comment: Yeah. You need to vote the best answer you're ever gonna get, up - then maybe I'll take the time to write it all out from scratch in a TD app. Same as you could, rather than just copy and paste from my brain power.

Comment: Sure dude, you deserve voting up, although I've tried your solution with no hope, so I've requested text format, anyways thanks again for your help.

Comment: The oldest version of TD I have is v6.2.  So here is  working version you can download and open in v3.0 .   I've tested it in v6.2 and it works just fine.  If you can't open the download ( because v3 is too old ) , I'll post up an alternate image, which you'll just have to type in from scratch.   But trust me , it does work.    https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/WinApi_Miscellaneous#Advanced_file_operations:_copy.2C_move.2C_rename_and_delete